# Laravel Api Controller Routes Not Getting Reached in Production

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I am using cpanel shared hosting to deploy my laravel api, every route works in development using `php artisan serve` 
I uploaded the application and modified the `public_html` to include the content of the `public` directory. It seems to be working because in the code below from the file `routes/api` I included only two routes to illustrate my point. 

Route `api/test` is working and returning the string "something" but when I try any other route and in this case the login route which I put the same lines of code in it as *test* I get a 200 status code with nothing in the response. I tried `dd()` too but can't seem to hit the route at all. 
***Routes/api***

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AppController;
use App\Http\Controllers\EmergencyContactController;
use App\Http\Controllers\GuardianController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PickupPeopleController;
use App\Http\Controllers\StudentController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ForgotPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ResetPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\BlogPostController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ImageController;
use App\Http\Controllers\EventController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ContactController;

Route::get('test', function () {
    return 'something';
});
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
```

***in the controllers/AuthController***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use App\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
public function login(Request $request)
{
    return 'something';
}
```

Comment: Upon further investigation I realized that if I change the route from POST to GET it gets executed so only GET requests are being handled.